# Displaytag Export Pdf does not show greek characters

Tags: displaytag

I am using displaytag library to display data from database. I am also use export options to excel and pdf. The encoding is ISO-8859-7 and i can see the results correctly to the exported excel file but i have problem with greek in pdf file:  instead of greek characters i see blancs. Any idea what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create a custom PdfView  class where you create the font BaseFont.createFont(FONT,"Cp1253", BaseFont.EMBEDDED); 
new Font(bf, 12);
FONT is the path to ARIALBD.TTF file  and it worked fine for greek characters.